# Plutus devcontainer build fails with 'devcontainer' not found

Tags: plutus, dev-container

I cloned the current plutus repo

```
git clone https://github.com/input-output-hk/plutus
```

And i'm on the current commit

```
3f8c1e22292d68d92f01f9a62a60621df01cdd4e
```

But building the dev container does not work (before some weeks it worked on the same machine)

```
wutze@wutze-pc:~/workspace/plutus$ sudo docker load < $(nix-build default.nix -A devcontainer)
error: attribute 'devcontainer' in selection path 'devcontainer' not found
-bash: $(nix-build default.nix -A devcontainer): ambiguous redirect
```

Any ideas what's wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The devcontainer is existing in this git commit

```
c801b70016856b320a0deaab1f35f7b1ca9efa27
```

They have moved the devcontainer to [The Plutus Application Framework](https://github.com/input-output-hk/plutus-apps)
As per the README in the plutus repository. This repository used to contain the code for the Plutus Application Framework and Marlowe. These have now moved:

```
Plutus Application Framework

Marlowe
```

Comment: thanks didn't notice that it was moved to a different repo