# WSL2 Plutus env setup - docker load error: attribute 'devcontainer' in selection path

Tags: plutus, plutus-pioneer-program, plutus-starter

docker load < $(nix-build default.nix -A devcontainer)
error: attribute 'devcontainer' in selection path 'devcontainer' not found
-bash: $(nix-build default.nix -A devcontainer): ambiguous
redirect

I'm following these instructions...
https://docs.plutus-community.com/docs/setup/WindowsWSL.html

Where should the command below be called? What directory? docker load < $(nix-build default.nix -A devcontainer)

Answer (score 0):

I've run into this issue as well. Looks like that container that is referenced is in the Plutus Application Framework Repo according to the answer here: [Plutus devcontainer build fails with 'devcontainer' not found](https://cardano.stackexchange.com/questions/4389/plutus-devcontainer-build-fails-with-devcontainer-not-found)

To get this to work, clone the plutus-apps repo found here: https://github.com/input-output-hk/plutus-apps

Run the steps from there with the following changes:
Building Plutus and a dev container

- Step 2: the repo needs to be updated to `https://github.com/input-output-hk/plutus-apps`

  - The devcontainer folder was moved to that repo
- Step 6: in creating the `/etc/nix/nix.conf` file, `sandbox = false` and `use-sqlite-wal = false` as the first two lines of that file. When I tried to run nix build it was choking on something to do w/ SQLite so I removed those 2 lines and that got past that
- Step 8: This command needs to be updated to the following:

  - `nix build -f default.nix plutus-apps.haskell.packages.plutus-pab.components.library`
- Step 11: If this fails with an error related to not having the kvm feature go to your `/etc/nix/nix.conf` file and add this line:

  - `system-features = nixos-test benchmark big-parallel kvm`
  - Go back to your repo and re run the command

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).